# How can I make an entity's collection a Set in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Say I'm building a model from a blank canvas in EF and I have a one-to-many relationship in the model (Category->Product or something). How can I make that collection (Category.Products) a Set (HashSet or similar) instead of a collection, so that I can enforce set constraints (such as uniqueness) at the model level?

Comment: Are you using Entity objects or POCOs? How do you generate your entities?

Answer (score 2):

I recently have moved to using POCO with Linq-To-Sql and really like the freedom it gives to not have to use EntitySet et al. So I think POCO is the answer for you, but I suspect (haven't researched it so can't answer definitively) there are going to be restrictions on what types you can use for your associations and the framework (EF or L2S) still be able to use them. For instance, you probably have to use something that derives from IList, or whatever.

I was looking at something vaguely similar a bit ago, and found that one of the features of EntitySet is the ability to subscribe to the Add and Remove events. There is an ObservableCollection type that also has similar functionality, so you can look into those. Otherwise, you're most probably stuck rolling your own.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks. The only reason I haven't marked this answer as 'accepted' is because I'm still not sure I can use any type of collection for POCO associations. I'll look into it and get back to this.